# How Do I Wait For A Message In Logs Before Starting A Service?

Tags: systemd

I have two Java services where the second one depends on the first being fully started before it can start.

In order to check that the first service is fully started I need to grep for a specific message in the logs (and also ignore previous start messages).

Can I add this search somewhere in the systemd files?

Comment: Couldn't one just sleep for a specific period of time which lets the first service have plenty of time to start?

Comment: You _could_ but I'd rather have a robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a "pre start" action in the unit file for doing your grep / sleep.
It's not pretty but something like that!

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "i=1; while [ $i -ne 0 ]; do grep pattern file; i=$?; sleep 5; done"
```

Comment: And drop everything you grepped before, to avoid acting on previous starts: `sed -n "${sometimestamp},$ p" | grep pattern logfile`  (and fill $sometimestamp after 'do', of course)

Comment: yep, not bad, or with a tail on the last lines